# Xcode Asset Catalog - is there a way to mark a sprite for iPad non-retina only?

Tags: ios, xcode, asset-catalog, app-thinning

I'd like the sprite in asset catalog to be available for iPad and iPad mini non-retina devices only. Is there a way to do this? It's possible to specify that the image is for iPad, but how to mark it for iPad non-retina only?

Answer (score 0):

Select `Assets` -> tap `+`(left bottom corner) -> New Image set -> select that newly added Image set -> select `Attribute inspector` -> `check the check box beside ipad`.

It will add a image set for your ipad (1x and 2x). add your 1x and 2x image on it. **`here 2x image is for retina display in ipad`.**